# Algorithm to sort passengers into their nearest vehicle until vehicles are full

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

I have a problem that is similar to the [bin packing problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/), however the problem is different:

- There are x vehicles, which could be anywhere in a 2D plane
- Each vehicle has passenger capacity y
- There are z passengers, which could be anywhere in a 2D plane

I'd like to write an algorithm to sort the passengers into the vehicles, within the following constraints:

1. Passengers must move to their closest vehicle
2. If a vehicle reaches capacity, no more passengers can move to it

I would like a pseudo-code algorithm as I'm not yet sure if I'll be implementing this in JavaScript, PHP or SQL. My first attempt is this:

1. Assign each passenger a numeric ID starting from 0 and incrementing by 1
2. Assign each vehicle a numeric ID starting from 0 and incrementing by 1
3. Create an array for each vehicle with the same name/ID as its vehicle ID
4. For each passenger, calculate the distance between it and all vehicles
5. Store the results in a passenger/vehicle array: `[passengerID, distance to vehicleID1, distance to vehicleID2, etc.]`
6. Repeat these step for z passengers:

   - Iterate over the array and find the smallest distance value. This should be the passenger who is closest to a vehicle
   - Add the passengerID to the vehicle array
   - Remove that passenger item from the passenger/vehicle array
   - Check the occupants of the vehicle array added to. If length equals capacity, nullify every instance of the passenger-distance value in the passenger/vehicle array

At the end of execution, we should have an empty passenger/vehicle array if number of passengers is less than total vehicle capacity, or a few elements left in that array if there are more passengers than would fit in all vehicles. We should also have arrays for each vehicle that have the same number of elements as their capacity, or possibly fewer if there were fewer passengers than vehicle capacity.

I am pretty sure the above will work, but I feel that there could be a more efficient method. I'm particularly concerned about calculating the distances between *every* passenger and vehicle to begin with, as this will be computationally expensive.

Can anyone point me to a more efficient solution?

Many thanks,
Arj

Comment: The best way to approach this is greedly with a divide & conquer combination, IMO (take a look at the closest pair problem). You are doing the most work, calculating the distance between every passenger & every car. So let's get rid of that. Sort the passengers & the vehicles based on their x-cordinates. Divide the plane into n groups (calculate on based on average capacity), & greedly place the passengers to the closest in the group. Merge the groups like we do in CP. This should give you ```O(nlogn)``` as apposed to ```O(nm)``` I don't think it is possible do better ```nlgn```

Comment: Also I doubt this can be properly implemented with SQL which is a simple DSL, so I don't even know why it is listed. But if you are really concerned about performance you should use C (or haskell or python), not a language where a simple addition is a 17 step algorithm

Comment: Hi sinanspd. I thinkyou need both x and y co-ordinates to solve this problem. Also, the reason I stated the languages is because I'm using a LAMP stack. It could be implemented in SQL with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the contributions. I have done the research and written my own code to solve this problem. It's quite complicated :( :

```
function loadUnits(originalPassengersAndVehicles) {
    // this function takes care of everything required to load any selected passenger(s) into the destination vehicle(s)
    var vehicles = []; // an array of all transport vehicles
    var passengers = []; // an array of all passengers
    var passengerVehicleDistances = []; // an array of the distance between all passengers and all vehicles. this is a 2-dimensional array, with the first dimension being all passengers and the second dimension being the distance between all vehicles for those passengers
    var unitsAndDestinations = []; // an array of all valid passengers and their destination (which should be a vehicle's position)
    var loadingNumbers = []; // store the number of units loading into the vehicles
    var errorMessage = "";
    var distance, currentPassenger;

    // store the vehicle(s) location as the destination
    var destination = {
        lat: null,
        lng: null
    };

    function smallestValue() {
        // this function iterates over the passengerVehicleDistances array to find the passenger which is closest to a vehicle. it ignores any distances that are negative, since these would be passengers that are flagged as boarding/boarded
        var returnValue = {
            distance: 2000, // used as a comparison of passengers' shortest distances to vehicles in the passengerVehicleDistances array. we set the value to double passenger's maximum move distance
            passengerIndex: -1, // used to store the passenger index of the shortest distance between a passenger and a vehicle in the passengerVehicleDistances array
            vehicleIndex: -1 // used to store the vehicle index of the shortest distance between a passenger and a vehicle in the passengerVehicleDistances array
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < vehicles.length; j++) {     
                if (passengerVehicleDistances[i][j] < returnValue.distance &&
                    passengerVehicleDistances[i][j] > 0) {
                    returnValue.distance = passengerVehicleDistances[i][j];
                    returnValue.passengerIndex = i;
                    returnValue.vehicleIndex = j;
                }
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    // iterate through all selected passengers and assign valid transport vehicles to the vehicles array and valid passenger to the passengers array
    for (var key in originalPassengersAndVehicles) {
        if (originalPassengersAndVehicles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].userID == gv.user.ID &&
                originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].selected) {
                if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].capacity > 0) {
                    // if the vehicle is moving, show an error message and don't assign it to the vehicles array
                    if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].moving) {
                        errorMessage = "Cannot load passenger into a moving " + originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].type + ".";
                        clickedError(originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].position, -30, 0, errorMessage);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if the vehicle is currently full, show an error message and don't assign it to the vehicles array
                    if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].occupants >= originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].capacity) {
                        errorMessage = capitalizeFirstLetter(originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].type) + " is full.";
                        clickedError(originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].position, -20, 0, errorMessage);
                        continue;
                    }

                    vehicles.push(key); // add this vehicle to the array
                    loadingNumbers.push(0); // add another array element to loading numbers for this vehicle
                }

                else if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].type == "passenger") {
                    // if the passenger is already being loaded into another vehicle, show an error message and don't assign it to the passengers array
                    if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].loading.length > 0) {
                        errorMessage = "That passenger passenger is already boarding another vehicle.";
                        clickedError(originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].position, -30, 0, errorMessage);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if the passenger is already onboard another vehicle, show an error message and don't assign it to the passengers array. note that this is the same procedure as above, but we want to show a different error message
                    if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].holding.length > 0) {
                        errorMessage = "That passenger passenger is already in another vehicle.";
                        clickedError(originalPassengersAndVehicles[key].position, -30, 0, errorMessage);
                        continue;
                    }

                    passengers.push(key); // add this passenger to the array
                    passengerVehicleDistances.push([]); // add an empty array element to the passengers and vehicles distance array for each vehicle to be processed below
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // if either passengers or vehicles are empty, show an error message, disable the load button to prevent the player clicking it again (i.e. force him to try a different selection), and quit this function 
    if (vehicles.length == 0) {
        errorMessage = "No valid vehicles selected to load passenger.";
        clickedError(gv.map.getCenter(), 0, 0, errorMessage);
        gv.o("transportIcon").style.display = "none"; // hide the load icon
        return;
    }

    if (passengers.length == 0) {
        errorMessage = "No valid passenger selected to board vehicles.";
        clickedError(gv.map.getCenter(), 0, 0, errorMessage);
        gv.o("transportIcon").style.display = "none"; // hide the load icon
        return;
    }

    // iterate over the passengers and vehicles arrays and calculate the distances between each passenger and each vehicle. this loop generates the passengerVehicleDistances array, which then needs to be processed for assigning passengers to vehicles
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < vehicles.length; j++) {         
            // calculate the distance between the passenger's current position and the vehicle's current position
            distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(originalPassengersAndVehicles[passengers[i]].position, originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[j]].position); // in metres

            passengerVehicleDistances[i].push(distance); // add the distance to the array
        }
    }

    // calculate the best apportionment of passengers to vehicles. passengers should move to their closest vehicles until that vehicle is full
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        currentPassenger = smallestValue(); // iterate over our passengerVehicleDistances array and find the passenger closest to a vehicle who hasn't yet been processed. note that we don't use i below, as the iteration over this loop isn't the same as the current closest passenger index

        // first we check for -1 in passenger and vehicle indices. if this is the case, then smallestValue() has not found any values in passengerVehicleDistances so we can stop the loop and process unitsAndDestinations
        if (currentPassenger.passengerIndex == -1 && currentPassenger.vehicleIndex == -1) {
            break; // end the loop since there are no longer any valid distances in passengerVehicleDistances
        }

        // check the vehicle this passenger has been assigned to. if it's now full, show an error message and invalidate all distances related to it in passengerVehicleDistances
        if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].occupants >= originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].capacity) {
            for (var j = 0; j < passengerVehicleDistances.length; j++) {
                passengerVehicleDistances[j][currentPassenger.vehicleIndex] = -1;
            }

            errorMessage = capitalizeFirstLetter(originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].type) + " is full.";
            clickedError(originalPassengersAndVehicles[passengers[currentPassenger.passengerIndex]].position, -20, 0, errorMessage);
            continue;
        }

        // check if this passenger will fit into this vehicle based on the vehicle's current occpants, units currently boarding and its capacity. first, we calculate the true loading figure as we can't just count the loading array as each unitID may be a passenger group      
        loadingNumbers[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex] += originalPassengersAndVehicles[passengers[currentPassenger.passengerIndex]].totalUnits;

        // then we add the vehicle's current occupants with the loading number and check if loading this passenger would put it over capacity. if the passenger can board, but the vehicle will be full when this passenger boards, invalidate all distances related to this vehicle in passengerVehicleDistances
        if (originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].occupants + loadingNumbers[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex] > originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].capacity) {
            // the passenger cannot board (i.e. its totalUnits is greater than available capacity). ideally, in this circumstance the passenger should try to board all other vehicles in ascending distance order. if it can't board any other vehicle, then we can remove the passenger from processing
            // insert code here

            for (var j = 0; j < passengerVehicleDistances.length; j++) {
                passengerVehicleDistances[j][currentPassenger.vehicleIndex] = -1;
            }

            errorMessage = capitalizeFirstLetter(originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].type) + " will be full.";
            clickedError(originalPassengersAndVehicles[passengers[currentPassenger.passengerIndex]].position, -20, 0, errorMessage);
            continue;
        }

        // if this distance is too far, then the distance to every other vehicle will also be too far
        if (currentPassenger.distance > originalPassengersAndVehicles[passengers[i]].range_move) {
            // show an error message
            errorMessage = "This passenger is too far to load.";
            clickedError(originalPassengersAndVehicles[passengers[currentPassenger.passengerIndex]].position, -10, 0, errorMessage);

            // remove the passenger from the distances array so that it's not processed again
            for (var j = 0; j < passengerVehicleDistances[currentPassenger.passengerIndex].length; j++) {
                passengerVehicleDistances[currentPassenger.passengerIndex][j] = -1;
            }

            continue;
        }

        // only add the passenger to the vehicle if it passes the above checks (within movement range, vehicle not currently full or will be full). move this passenger directly to its closest vehicle (i.e. directly to the same grid square occupied by the vehicle)
        destination.lat = roundToDecimal(originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].position.lat() - (gv.gridUnit / 2), 6);
        destination.lng = roundToDecimal(originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].position.lng() - (gv.gridUnit / 2), 6);

        // if we are ok to load, add the passenger to unitsAndDestinations
        unitsAndDestinations.push([passengers[currentPassenger.passengerIndex], destination]);

        // remove the passenger from the distances array so that it's not processed again
        for (var j = 0; j < passengerVehicleDistances[currentPassenger.passengerIndex].length; j++) {
            passengerVehicleDistances[currentPassenger.passengerIndex][j] = -1;
        }

        // flag the transport vehicle as loading the units
        originalPassengersAndVehicles[vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]].loading.push(passengers[currentPassenger.passengerIndex]);

        // flag the passenger as boarding the vehicle
        originalPassengersAndVehicles[passengers[currentPassenger.passengerIndex]].loading.push(vehicles[currentPassenger.vehicleIndex]);
    }

    // only send something to the server and update the client if at least 1 passenger can be vaildly loaded
    if (unitsAndDestinations.length > 0) {
        // send the array of units and their destinations to the server for checking and database updating
        serverProcessing(unitsAndDestinations);
        gv.o("transportIcon").style.display = "none"; // hide the load icon
    }
}
```

This is a pure JavaScript implementation, but I have tested it in my app and it does work (as far as I can see). Hopefully someone else will find the code useful.

Cheers,
Arj

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bin packing problem, which is good news because bin packing is NP hard.

Rather it's a minimum weight bipartite matching problem (also called "assignment problem") where the weights are distances. One vertex set has an element for each customer. The other has a vertex for each vehicle seat. There's one edge for each feasible vehicle-customer pairing. The weight on the edge is the distance between the two.

Note many presentations of assignment problem algorithms solve for a *maximum* weight matching. No worries. To solve a minimum weight problem, just negate the weights. The classical solution is the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), which will be O(n^3) in the number of vertices. However your problem is a special version called Euclidean bipartite matching. There exist asymptotically faster algorithms for this case. [Here's a survey paper](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf). I have no idea of these are faster in practice. The Hungarian algorithm is simple, with very low overhead.

In practice, solving for a few thousand vertices is not a problem, but PHP, javascript, or SQL are not the best tools for very computation-intensive algorithms like this one. If you *must* choose one of the three, use javascript and make sure it's in an environment with an excellent JIT compiler.

Finding the minimum weight matching will correspond to putting people in vehicles in a way that minimizes the total distance from customers to their vehicles.

Comment: Hi Gene, and thanks for your contribution. However, I was really looking for an algorithm from someone. The Hungarian algorithm seems close, but not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Arj Well that's as may be. Your algorithm is essentially greedy. The Hungarian algorithm is simpler and produces an optimal answer.  But I'm glad you're happy.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, any algorithm must make use of both dimensions. If you project all points onto the x plane or y plane then you lose one dimension of information. So you must measure the distance between any vehicle / passenger pair.

Once you do this you can think of it as a region growing algorithm:

- Uniformly grow a region (circle) around each vehicle.
- As soon as a passenger is included in the region for a vehicle then that passenger is assigned to that vehicle
- When a vehicle reaches it's capacity, stop growing the region

In code, the start would be the same but you can speed it up slightly with sorting:

- Create an array for each vehicle, storing the distance to each passenger
- Take the unique values across all of these arrays and sort them in ascending order
- Then iterate through this unique list of distances. For each distance assign passengers who have that distance across each array.
- When a vehicle reaches its capacity, remove that array.

Comment: Hi mattyx17. I agree that you need both dimensions, however I don't think progressively growing a radius is an efficient solution as you'd get conflicts if both passengers and other vehicles are within that radius.